# Does iphone OS 4 support Web socket?

Tags: iphone, sockets

I am working on an investigation see how web sockets is supported in browser.
Firefox nightly build : Yes.
IE 9 Preview: No.

Can someone help me check if it's supported on Iphone OS4?
Please check it on following page:
http://jimbergman.net/websocket-web-browser-test/

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Safari on IOS 4.0.1: No.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, On iOS 4.2+ Mobile Safari supports it